# Word for "multi-influenced"

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, medical

I am looking for a word to describe a phenomenon that has multiple influences. For example, a disease that has many risk factors.

It can be used in a sentence such as:

> Although the disease is likely *{WORD}*, one factor is X.

*Multifactorial*? Is there another word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Multifactorial* is exactly what you are looking for as there is the term *multifactorial disease* in medicine also. Here is a good definition I've found:

> The term multifactorial means that there are many different influences acting together to cause the appearance of the disease. These include effects from a combination of genetic factors, none of which on its own would be likely to cause the disease, and environmental factors, which again would not cause the disease by themselves. It is believed that a particular combination of genetic and environmental factors act together in concert and trigger the development of multifactorial disease.
>
> <sub>(2008). Multifactorial Disease . In: Kirch, W. (eds) Encyclopedia of Public Health. Springer, Dordrecht. https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4020-5614-7_2248</sub>